# Strange margin on scaled SVG in IE10 and 11

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I want to display a list of SVG icons. This is working in all browsers except IE 10 and 11. IE is adding a strange invisible padding around the SVG.

I've placed SVG icons in a list like this:

```
<ul class="c-category-list">
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
</ul>
```

My css (sass) looks like this:

```
.c-category-list
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  &__item{
    display: inline-block;
  }

  &__image {
    height: 4em;
  }
}
```

I made a codepen for debugging purpose: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZLaae

In other browsers (`Firefox`, `Chrome`, etc.), it shows output like below:

[image]

But in `IE11` and `IE10`, all icons have a margin between each other. The output is like below:

[image]

Comment: try `padding: 0;` to  `&__item`

Comment: thnx, but this is not working

Comment: and `margin:0` ??

Comment: Nope, I don't think it's actual margin or padding behavior, but something that is requiring more space. Looks a bit like an IE bug..

Comment: i dont see any space in IE sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline;`, it seems that IE handles `inline-block` differently.

Here's the final SCSS:

```css
$component: "c-category-list";
.#{$component} {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  &__item{
    display: inline;
  }

  &__image {
    height: 4em;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Output with compiled SCSS should look like below:

```css
.c-category-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.c-category-list__item {  
  display: inline;
}

.c-category-list__image {
  height: 4em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-category-list">
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item">
    <a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKLqWe

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still see more space around the elements on IE11/10.  Compare this codepen on Chrome en IE10/11 for a better example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXmYOj

Comment: @Royw I've updated. Now what?? I guess this time it is working.

Comment: I posted a workaround my self, but this is way better. Thanks!

Comment: @Royw More update version here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXVzGa. Maybe you will like it and exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

1) Image it self has more space between left and right. So it shows space between images. Try to crop the image and try it again space will be removed.

2) After cropping images by using display: inline-block; there will be default space between images. Suggested way is use with display: flex.

Comment: Yes, i know. But the space in IE11/10 is a lot more than other browsers. It's not because of the space in the image i think. I also tried flex.

Answer (score 1):

This is an IE quirk, not sure if there is a better way but I've had to solve it by specifying the width and height of the svg in the past.

```css
.c-category-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
 }

.c-category-list__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-category-list__image {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-category-list">
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
  <li class="c-category-list__item"><a href="#" class="c-category-list__link"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/912/912316.svg" alt="" class="c-category-list__image"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like this is a bug in IE or something like that, but I found a work around for now. Instead of sizing the SVG directly, I sized the parent to a fixed height and gave the SVG 100% height. This seems to work.

```
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  height: 4em;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJMqLM